# Alignment of pgf plots with two y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

i need some help regarding alignment of tikzpictures, see the example.
To align the pgf plots with same x axis i use the "trim axis left". This works well for diagrams with a single y axis. Now one of the diagrams has a second y axis, then they aren't aligned well.
I want to align them and place them in the center of the page.

Any ideas?

Andreas

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\selectlanguage{german}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hang,font=singlespacing]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma, compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\subfloat[Plot1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight,
grid,
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel near ticks,
xmin=0,
xmax=6,
xlabel={t}]
\addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight,
axis  y  line*=right,
grid,
xmin=0,
xmax=6,
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel near ticks]
\addplot coordinates {(1,66.4)(2,43.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,9.4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Plot2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.3\textheight,
grid,
xmin=0,
xmax=6,
xlabel={t},
legend pos=north east]
\addplot coordinates {(1,6666.4)(2,433.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,9.4)};
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
}

\caption{Figure 1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\centering` command (after `\begin{figure}`) instead `center` environment. Your graphics have width too long, you can use `scale=0.5` (for example) like option in `tikzpicture` environment or in `axis` environment. Then, you can add `\hfill` or some command for horizontal separation between `subfloat`'s

Comment: This is a crosspost to the german forum [goLaTeX](http://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?p=72043#72043).

Answer (score 2):

Use the same option for the right hand side:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgf/number format/use comma,
  compat=1.12% current version
} 
\usepackage{subfig} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{figure} 
\begin{center} 
\subfloat[Plot1]{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right] 
    \begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight, 
    axis y line*=left,
    grid, 
    %xlabel near ticks, 
    %ylabel near ticks, 
    xmin=0, 
    xmax=6, 
    xlabel={t}] 
    \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)}; 
    \end{axis} 
% 
    \begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.35\textheight, 
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line=none,
    ymajorgrids,
    xmin=0, 
    xmax=6, 
    %xlabel near ticks,
    %ylabel near ticks
    ] 
    \addplot coordinates {(1,66.4)(2,43.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,9.4)}; 
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
} 

\subfloat[Plot2]{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right] 
      \begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.3\textheight, 
       grid, 
       xmin=0, 
       xmax=6, 
       xlabel={t}, 
       legend pos=north east] 
       \addplot coordinates {(1,6666.4)(2,433.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,9.4)}; 
       \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\caption{Schöner Mist} 
\end{center} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```