# Vertical alignment of two graphs misaligned because of axis data

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

Hope this is not a stupid question. I have the following two plots:
[image: Misaligned graphs]

As you can see the two y-axes are not aligned properly. I am not doing anything weird with the positioning I believe, as the two y labels are perfectly aligned. I believe the numbers on the y-axis of the top graph are moving the graph a bit on the right, resulting in a misalignment with respect to the bottom graph. Here is how I styled the two graphs:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend style={at={(1.05,1)}, anchor=north west,font=\tiny},
    xlabel=Delay (ms),
    ylabel=Number of Messages Executed,
    width=\textwidth/1.18,
    height=\textwidth/2.3,
    axis lines=middle,
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
    axis line style={->},
]
\addplot{
    %plot data
};
%more plots
\legend{C1P1,C1P2,C2P1,C2P2,C3P1,C3P2,C4P1,C4P2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    width=\textwidth/1.18,
    height=\textwidth/2.3,
    boxplot/draw direction=y, 
    x axis line style={opacity=0}, 
    axis x line*=bottom, 
    axis y line=left, 
    enlarge y limits, 
    ymajorgrids, 
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 
    xticklabels={\footnotesize{C1P1},\footnotesize{C1P2},\footnotesize{C2P1},\footnotesize{C2P2},\footnotesize{C3P1},\footnotesize{C3P2},\footnotesize{C4P1},\footnotesize{C4P2}},
    ylabel={Queue Size}
]
%plots
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\label{blabla}
\caption{blabla}
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\end{figure*}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check section **4.19.3 Horizontal Alignment** from the pgfplots manual.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247885/alignment-of-pgf-plots-with-two-y-axis. Try adding the options `[trim axis left,trim axis right]`, to exclude the labels from width computations.

Comment: Trimming the space doesn't do the work as it moves the top graph all the way to the left, breaking the indentation of the page. While by looking at the pgfplots manual I tried giving a `name=delay` to the top graph and adding `at=(delay.below south west), anchor=north west,` to the bottom graph but the result is *identical*.

Comment: That's surprising. However, since you didn't provide a working MWE it's not reproducible for me.
It seemed to work fine for me with this approach.

Comment: That is not surprising if you are using two separate `tikzpicture` environments, but if the two `axis` environments are in the same `tikzpicture` environment, that should work. Edit: You could also have a look at the `groupplots` library.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. correct - thanks for the comment. I actually overlooked that fact and edited it in my answer without realizing....  ;)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment above - this works properly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(1.05,1)}, anchor=north west,font=\tiny},
xlabel=Delay (ms),
ylabel=Number of Messages Executed,
width=\textwidth/1.18,
height=\textwidth/2.3,
axis lines=middle,
x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
axis line style={->},
name=main plot
]

\addplot table {
    x y
    1 .1
    2 2
    3 .5
    %plot data
};
%more plots
\legend{C1P1,C1P2,C2P1,C2P2,C3P1,C3P2,C4P1,C4P2}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ at={(main plot.below south west)},yshift=-0.1cm,
anchor=north west,
 width=\textwidth/1.18,
height=\textwidth/2.3,
boxplot/draw direction=y, 
x axis line style={opacity=0}, 
axis x line*=bottom, 
axis y line=left, 
enlarge y limits, 
ymajorgrids, 
xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 
xticklabels={\footnotesize{C1P1},\footnotesize{C1P2},\footnotesize{C2P1},\footnotesize{C2P2},\footnotesize{C3P1},\footnotesize{C3P2},\footnotesize{C4P1},\footnotesize{C4P2}},
ylabel={Queue Size}
]
%plots
\addplot table {
    x y
    1 100
    2 200
    3 400
    %plot data
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\label{blabla}
\caption{blabla}
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

If it doesn't for you, please provide a full working MWE. [image: screenshot]